# Exclude a Flutter package from an Xcode target for iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, package, cross-platform

I am using a custom package for my app on Flutter. The swift code for iOS in that package uses some static files. Having multiple targets (say **T1, T2 & T3**) in my app I would like to exclude the package from target T3 since it does not use that package and the file should not be inside the T3 ipa. Is this possible? Is there a workaround?